# HTML5 Javascript/jQuery Video MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, localhost

I have a web application which is intermittently producing an error when using `Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m`.

I am using the HTML5 `<video />` tag and controlling the `src` attribute using `javascript`.

The page which is causing the error sometimes errors on the first video or on the seventh. There is no predictable pattern.

Here is the `javascript` which handles the `src`:

```
var playing = false;
var media = $('#video')[0];

function initModule() {
    $.ajax({
        url: recap,
        type:'HEAD',
        error:
        function(){
            screenNotify('Error!', false, "404: Module video content could not be found." + recap, true);
        },
        success:
        function() {
            media.src = recap;
            registerListeners(media);
            media.load();
        }
    });
}

function registerListeners(listen) {
    listen.addEventListener('ended', hide_recap);
    listen.addEventListener('error', mediaError);
}

function mediaError(event) {
    screenNotify('Media Error!', false, "Media failed with code: " + event.currentTarget.error.code, true);
}

function play_recap() {
    if (!playing) {
        playing = true;
        media.play();
    }
}

function hide_recap() {
    if (playing) {
        playing = false;
        media.pause();
        media.currentTime = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Interestingly, there is no error thrown when I call `media.load()`, instead, you need to look at the network requests to see that the `GET` has actually produced a result of `(failed)`.

[image]

Another thing to note, is this `GET` status only occurs for videos which reside within this particular folder location: `/interactive/vids/recap/`. The error does not occur anywhere else within the application.

Finally, the last thing which is strange about this error, is when the application finally attempts to play the video from `play_recap()`, about 1 second of the video will actually play, followed by an error being thrown on the `video` element.

The error is `MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK` however this application is installed locally on a `Tomcat` server and is running under `localhost`.

So why is the `GET` request producing `(failed)` and the `HTML5` `<video>` element producing a `MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK` when everything is only ever running on `localhost`?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed very similar issue with `Chrome 31`. I'm getting inconsistently `MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK`, all other tested browsers work fine.

I haven't found any other solution than just retrying - you could try recreate the `video` element or just change `currentTime` - it always helps in my case.

Comment: I will keep those ideas in mind. It was also only happening on one clients network and no others. Really strange. I have not tried changing the current time so I will keep that in mind if they come back with the problem again. Interestingly, if I got them to run the application with their PC disconnected from their network they had no troubles, and since it was not possible to go in and debug onsite I unfortunately never could track down the exact cause. Thanks for the ideas though. I can only up vote since I have no way to test or confirm at this stage.

Comment: @SandorA: any solution to the problem?

Comment: Yes, I need a solution either, also have a Tomcat7 as a backend web-server and use mp4 streaming.